# Dialog is shown twice

Tags: android, android-layout

In my android app I have the following code in the OnCreate function:

```
txtUsername.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String Username = txtUsername.getText().toString();

            if (arg1 == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                DontShowDialog = false;
                if ((Username.toLowerCase().endsWith("blabla.com") == false && Username.toLowerCase().endsWith("blabla-bla.nl") == false) || validateEmail(Username) == false) {
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(arg0.getContext());
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.startdialog);
                    dialog.setTitle("Warning 1");

                    Button btOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btOk);
                    btOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            DontShowDialog = true;
                            dialog.dismiss();

                            return;
                        }
                    });

                    if (DontShowDialog == false) {
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }

            txtUsername.clearFocus();
            txtPassword.setNextFocusDownId(txtPassword.getId());
            return false;
        }
    });
```

When the user hits the NEXT button and the username is not right, a dialog is shown which can be canceled by the OK button.
But.... after hitting the OK button, the dialog is shown again... I don't want that.

Why is that happening?

rg,
Eric

Comment: What if you change the `return;` to `return true;`, seems to me like your `onKey` method needs a `boolean` and by just returning here it cycles through the `onKey` again and resets `DontShowDialog` to `false`

Comment: show us the your activity code are u using DontShowDialog else where

Comment: @Asok That return is for the OnClick event.

Comment: @Nammari That variable is not changed anywhere else.

Comment: Here you wrote that user click on "next button" and you write this code on "txtUsername"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

moved the line

```
DontShowDialog = true;
```

from the OnClick part

Changed the if-then below the onClick to:

```
if (DontShowDialog == false) {
                        dialog.show();
                        DontShowDialog = true;
                        return false;
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

By returning `false` in your `onKey()` event, you're telling Android that the `KeyEvent` was not consumed - so my guess is that changing the return statement to `true` might fix the problem, because Android would know the event was consumed, and it would not re-enter the `onKey()` method.  If you could try that out and share the results that would be great!

Comment: I have tried various returns, but no luck.

As I see it, inside the OnClick event I should get out of the OnKey event, but I suspect that is not possible?

Comment: I'm surprised it let's you put a blank `return` in there... normally you *have* to return a `boolean`.  Have you tried taking out the `return` inside the `OnClick()` completely?

Comment: OnClick is a void, so it doesn't allow a return boolean.
I have removed the return, but nothing changed. Dialog still comes back right after clicking the ok button on it.

Comment: Ah, forgot that the `return` is inside of `OnClick()`.  Personally, I think the two focus methods at the end are somehow re-triggering the `onKey()` method.  Add breakpoints at crucial lines, then figure out how things flow - the Eclipse debugger is your best friend at this point :)

Comment: Eclipse debugger is more my enemy. After stepping from dialog.dismiss(); I get a Class Editor Source not found message.

Comment: Okay... in that case, I would recommend putting your code in a `try/catch` block, and analyzing the resulting `Exception`